# When does convolution erase non-monotonicities?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, convolution

Suppose $\phi:\Bbb R\to[0,\beta]$ is a bounded continuous function such that $\phi(-\infty)=0$ and $\phi(\infty)=\beta$.

Assume $\phi$ is non-decreasing except near zero, i.e. there exists $r>0$ such that $\phi$ is non-decreasing on $\Bbb R\setminus[-r,r]$, but it  may be decreasing on subsets of $[-r,r]$. (Assume also that $r$ is minimal.)

Suppose $k$ is a probability density, and I want to take the convolution

$$ (k*\phi)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}k(x-y)\phi(y)dy $$

I think that if $r$ is small and the variance of $k$ is large, then $k*\phi$ should be monotone, i.e. the non-monotonicities in $\phi$ were "eroded away" by convolution with $k$. Are there any results in terms of $r$ and the variance of $k$?

Comment: Imagine a symmetric p.d.f. $k$ which is concentrated on two tiny intervals $[a,a+\epsilon]$ and $[-a-\epsilon,-a]$, where $a$ is large. Then $k$ can have arbitrarily large variance (roughly $a$), but $k * \phi(x)$ can be arbitrarily close to $\tfrac{1}{2}(\phi(x + a) - \phi(x - a))$ (by making $\epsilon$ small). Thus, $k * \phi$ will fail to be monotone near $a$ and $-a$.

Comment: Are you interested in results with additional assumptions on $k$?  E.g., assuming that it's Lipschitz with constant $r$?

Comment: @BillBradley I am interested in any assumption on $\phi$ and $k$ which guarantees my conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that for all real $x$ 
$$\phi(x):=f(x):=\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if }x\le-1, \\
 1-|x| &\text{ if } -1<x\le 1, \\
 1-1/x &\text{ if }  x>1  
\end{cases}
$$
and 
$$k(x):=k_b(x):=\frac1{2b}\,1_{|x|<b},
$$
where $b>1/2$. Then for any such $b$ and any real $x$ 
$$(f*k_b)'(x)=\frac1{2b}\,\int_{-b}^b f'(x-t)\,dt=\frac{f(x+b)-f(x-b)}{2b},
$$
where $f'$ is the almost-everywhere derivative of the absolutely continuous function $f$. So, 
$$(f*k_b)'(b)=\frac{f(2b)-f(0)}{2b}=-\frac1{4b^2}<0. 
$$

So, here the convolution does not fully erase the non-monotonicity on the interval $[-1,1]$, however large the variance of $k$ is.

Here are graphs of $f$ (left) and $f*k_b$ (right, for $b=5$):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Iosif Pinelis' post answers your question as stated.  In case you're thinking about modifying your assumptions to guarantee monotonicity, here are a few observations.

Let $\beta=1$.  Let $\psi=(k * \phi)$ and suppose that $\phi$ is non-decreasing.  Suppose that $\phi$ and $k$ are differentiable (and hence $\psi$ is continuous and differentiable).

Then we can interpret $\psi$ as the CDF of some continuous random variable $X_{\psi}$, $k$ the pdf of some continuous r.v. $X_k$, and $\phi$ the CDF of a r.v. with negative probability ([see, e.g., Wikipedia on that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_probability)).  Then
$$X_k + X_{\phi} = X_{\psi}$$
i.e.,
$$k * \phi = \psi$$

However, we aren't given $k$ or $\psi$.  Suppose we are given only $\phi$.  Then, per [Ruzsa and Szekely](https://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01352002), we can always find some $k$ and $\psi$ that satisfy the equations above, i.e., for any $\phi$, there is some kernel $k$ that will make $\phi$ non-decreasing.

Of course, this doesn't provide a **single** $k$ for all $\phi$, but perhaps it's enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the negative answer above, here is a positive answer, now with the kernel 
\begin{equation}
k(x):=k_b(x):=\frac1b\,\max\Big(0,1-\frac{|x|}b\Big), \tag{0} 
\end{equation}
where $b>0$. For $f:=\phi$ and any real $x$, writing 
$(f*k)'(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}k'(x-y)f(y)dy$, where $k'$ is the almost-everywhere derivative of the absolutely continuous function $k$. So, 
$$b^2(f*k)'(x)=\int_{-b}^b[f(x+t)-f(x-t)]\,dt
=\int_x^{x+b}-\int_{x-b}^x, 
$$
where $\int_c^d:=\int_c^d f(x)\,dx$.

So, we have to show that 
\begin{equation*}
 \int_x^{x+b}\overset{\text{?}}\ge\int_{x-b}^x  \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
for some large enough $b>0$ and all real $x$.

The conditions $f(-\infty)=0$ and $f(\infty)=1$ are qualitative and need to be quantified in order to figure out how large $b$ have to be. Specifically, assume that 
\begin{equation*}
 2(1-f(u))<f(u)-f(-1), \quad f(u)>f(2), \quad3f(u)\ge2+f(2). \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
for some real $u>2$. How large $b$ needs to be will depend only on $u$. Assume $b\ge6$ throughout.

By symmetry, wlog $x\ge0$. So, we have the following cases.

*Case 1: $0\le x\le1$.* Then 
\begin{equation*}
 \int_x^{x+b}\ge \int_u^b\ge f(u)(b-u), 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{x-b}^x=\int_{-1}^x+\int_{x-b}^{-1}\le2+f(-1)(b-x-1)\le2+f(-1)b\le f(u)(b-u)
\end{equation*}
if 
\begin{equation*}
 b\ge b_1(u):=\frac{2+uf(u)}{f(u)-f(-1)}, 
\end{equation*}
so that (1) holds in Case 1.

*Case 2: $1\le x\le b/2-1$.* Write here
\begin{align}
 \int_x^{x+b}&=\int_x^{2x-1}+\int_{2x-1}^{2x+1}+\int_{2x+1}^{x+b/2}+\int_{x+b/2}^{x+b}, \\ 
 \int_{x-b}^x&=\int_1^x+\int_{-1}^1+\int_{x-b/2}^{-1}+\int_{x-b}^{x-b/2}. 
\end{align}
The integrals on the right-hand side of the latter equality match the corresponding integrals on the right-hand side of the penultimate equality; in particular, the matching integrals are taken over intervals of the same length. 
Since $f$ increases on $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$, we have 
\begin{equation}
\int_x^{2x-1}\ge\int_1^x,\quad \int_{2x+1}^{x+b/2}\ge\int_{x-b/2}^{-1}.  
\end{equation}
Next, $\int_{-1}^1\le2$ and $\int_{2x-1}^{2x+1}\ge0$, so that 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{2x-1}^{2x+1}\ge\int_{-1}^1-2. 
\end{equation}
Next, $\int_{x+b/2}^{x+b}\ge f(u)b/2$ if $b\ge2u$, and $\int_{x-b}^{x-b/2}\le f(-1)b/2$, by the Case 2 condition. So, (1) holds in Case 2 if 
\begin{equation*}
 b\ge b_2(u):=\max\Big[2u,\frac4{f(u)-f(-1)}\Big].  
\end{equation*}

*Case 3: $b/2-1\le x\le b-1$.* Then $x\ge2$. Write here
\begin{align}
 \int_x^{x+b}
 &=\int_x^{2x-2}+\int_{2x-2}^{2x-1}+\int_{2x-1}^{2x+1}+\int_{2x+1}^{x+b}, \\ 
 \int_{x-b}^x&=\int_2^x+\int_1^2+\int_{-1}^1+\int_{x-b}^{-1}, 
\end{align}
with similar matching of the right-hand side integrals. 
Since $f$ increases on $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$, we have 
\begin{equation}
\int_x^{2x-2}\ge\int_2^x,\quad \int_{2x+1}^{x+b}\ge\int_{x-b}^{-1}.  
\end{equation}
Next, $\int_{2x-2}^{2x-1}\ge f(u)$ if $b\ge4+u$ and $\int_1^2\le f(2)$, so that 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{2x-2}^{2x-1}\ge\int_1^2+f(u)-f(2). 
\end{equation}
Further, $\int_{2x-1}^{2x+1}\ge2f(u)$, and $\int_{-1}^1\le2$, so that 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{2x-1}^{2x+1}\ge\int_{-1}^1+2f(u)-2
\end{equation}
So, by (2), (1) holds in Case 3, if 
\begin{equation}
 b\ge b_3(u):=4+u. 
\end{equation}

*Case 4: $b-1<x<b+1$.* Then $-1<x-b<1$. Write here
\begin{align}
 \int_x^{x+b}
 &=\int_x^{2x-2}+\int_{2x-2}^{2x-1}+\int_{2x-1}^{x+b}, \\ 
 \int_{x-b}^x&=\int_2^x+\int_1^2+\int_{x-b}^1, 
\end{align}
with similar matching of the right-hand side integrals. 
Since $f$ increases on $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$, we have 
\begin{equation}
\int_x^{2x-2}\ge\int_2^x.  
\end{equation}
Next, $\int_{2x-2}^{2x-1}\ge f(u)$ if $b\ge4+u$ and $\int_1^2\le f(2)$, so that 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{2x-2}^{2x-1}\ge\int_1^2+f(u)-f(2). 
\end{equation} 
Further, $\int_{2x-1}^b\ge f(u)(b+1-x)$ if $b\ge4+u$, and $\int_{x-b}^1\le b+1-x$, so that 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{2x-1}^b\ge\int_{x-b}^1+(f(u)-1)(b+1-x)\ge\int_{x-b}^1+2f(u)-2. 
\end{equation}
So, by (2), (1) holds in Case 3, if 
\begin{equation}
 b\ge b_3(u)=4+u. 
\end{equation}

*Case 5: $x\ge b+1$.* Then (1) obviously holds, because $f$ increases on $(1,\infty)$.

So, (1) holds in all cases if (2) holds and 
\begin{equation}
 b\ge\max(b_1(u),b_2(u),b_3(u)). 
\end{equation}

So, here the convolution does fully erase the non-monotonicity on the interval $[-1,1]$, if the variance of $k$ is large enough.

---

Using similar (actually, a bit simpler) reasoning, one can prove the following more general result: Suppose that a locally integrable function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is nondecreasing on $\mathbb R\setminus[-r,r]$ for some real $r>0$, $f(-\infty+)=0$, and $f(\infty-)=c\in(0,\infty)$. Then the condition 
\begin{equation}
 \forall x\in[-r,r]\quad \int_x^\infty(c-f)>0\quad\text{and}\quad
 \int_{-\infty}^x f>0 \tag{*}
\end{equation}
is sufficient for the existence of a real $b>0$ such that $f*k_b$ is nondecreasing on $\mathbb R$, where $k_b$ is as defined in (0). Moreover, condition (*) becomes necessary if the two instances of $>$ there are replaced by $\ge$.

Unfortunately, I may be unable to post the proof of this result in the next few days.